# What is the proper workflow for when you need to switch machines, but aren't ready to commit?

Tags: git, version-control

I work on two machines, one in my lab and one at home.  I often start doing work in the lab, and want to continue at home, but the code is not in a state that I'd like to commit.  What is the proper workflow for handling this situation with git?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just SSH into the lab machine from home.  A command line in an xterm looks just the same as a command line through an ssh in an xterm.

Also remember to use [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).  That way, you can continue your editor sessions, leave compile results "on the screen" for future review, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to create another branch for while you're developing between computers, and only merge it into the trunk when you're committing the actual code.  That way you can commit to get the code pushed to the repository and available between machines, but still keep it separate from the 'finished' code.

Answer (score 0):

you just commit to a development branch and work on it till the thing is ready and then commit it to the production branch....